# Inserting array data into a single longtext field with php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to insert everything from an array created by this:

```
  $test = $_POST['productinfo'];
            $total2 = 0;
            $totalquantity = 0;
            $totalamount = 0;
            for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
            list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
            echo "Name: ".$name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Amount: ".$quantity;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Price: ".$total . "€";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br/>";
            $total2 += $total;
            $totalquantity += $quantity;
            $names[] = $name;
            $totalamount++;
}
            $_SESSION['totalprice'] = $total2;
            $_SESSION['totalquantity'] = $totalquantity;
            for($i=0; $i < $totalamount; $i++) {

              $_SESSION['product'] = $name[$i] ;
              print_r($names[$i]);
            }
```

into the database within a single variable, the variable being the `$_SESSION['product'] = $name[$1]` but it won't enter everything into the database with just that, is there a way to push all the data from an array into a single variable which could then be used to insert everything into the database into a specific row?

Comment: You single variable is $_SESSION['product'] ?

Comment: Should be, yes, it's used later on in another page in the form of `$product = $_SESSION['product'];` to make it into another variable to be used in inserting data to the database, but I firstly do need the data to be inside the session so I can take it forward to the next page

Comment: Try convert array to json using json_encode, and save to variable as string

Later you can json_decode to get the array back.

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria How would I do that? I have never meddled around with Json at all

Comment: try ```$_SESSION['product'] = json_encode($names)``` and no need for-loop down there.

Comment: try `$_SESSION['product'] .=  $name[$i];` and try `var_dump($_SESSION['product'])`; instead of `print($name[$i]);`

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria okay this worked pretty nicely, thank you for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on my comment, try to use `json_encode` to store the array as string.

```
$test = $_POST['productinfo'];
$total2 = 0;
$totalquantity = 0;
$totalamount = 0;

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
    list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
    echo "Name: ".$name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Amount: ".$quantity;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Price: ".$total . "€";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br/>";
    $total2 += $total;
    $totalquantity += $quantity;
    $names[] = $name;
    $totalamount++;
}

$_SESSION['totalprice'] = $total2;
$_SESSION['totalquantity'] = $totalquantity;
$_SESSION['product'] = json_encode($names) ;
```

You should be able to see how it is store by printing it out

```
print_r(json_encode($names));
```

And to get back the array, simply use `json_decode` function

```
$names = json_decode($_SESSION['product'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode to serialize the array like this :

`$your_var_for_DB = json_encode($_SESSION['product']);`

and use $your_var_for_DB into you insert query.

To reuse the value in an other place you will need to decode it like this :

`$your_var = json_decode($your_db_var);`

and $your_var will be you array with all the data.